# Compile errors while migrating php extension from 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I'm taking a look at an existing php extension and am trying to re-target it from 7.2 toward 7.3. What 7.3 api changes do I need to make to fix these build errors?

I have reviewed the internals upgrading guidance and it remains unclear to me what exactly is going on\has changed with the GC_FLAGS macro.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.3.0/UPGRADING.INTERNALS

Faulting line example:

```
GC_FLAGS(common_strings.__construct) |= IS_STR_INTERNED;
```

(and many more)
https://github.com/tpunt/pht/blob/master/pht.c#L53-L98

Returned error example:

```
ext\pht\pht.c(53): error C2106: '|=': left operand must be l-value
```

(and many more) https://ci.appveyor.com/project/NxSys/pht/builds/26576298/job/40hva8w8akd3qguw#L231

Build Env: MSVC15 on Win10 (Visual Studio 2017)

Any thoughts\direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My only thoughts are that `GC_FLAGS()` used to be returning a reference that could be modified, but no longer. I can't find any documentation to support that, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this instead (untested):

```
GC_ADD_FLAGS(common_strings.__construct, IS_STR_INTERNED);
```

And of course GC_DEL_FLAGS() to remove it.